# Replace generic Java Icons in Package Explorer in Ecplise with icons similar to the ones in Hierarchy View

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to replace the generic JAVA icon in eclipse with an icon that indicates whats inside (class interface...) basically to go from this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

but in *Package Explorer* rather than *Type Hierarchy View*.

Comment: As there could be several classes or interfaces inside a single file (remind: only one public), this would be a more difficult task than you might think of. In fact you can expand the file in the package or project explorer and see the declared types, too.

Comment: as intelliJ does it for scala and java I assumed its not that big of a task.

[link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/IntelliJ_IDEA_12.0.4_Ultimate.jpg)